# Pandas - How to use multiple cols for mapping (without merging)?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like as below

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': ['abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com','ace@gmail.com','ace@gmail.com','pqr@gmail.com','pqr@gmail.com'],
             'company': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
             'dept_access':['a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2']})

key_df = pd.DataFrame({'p_id': ['abc@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com','pqr@gmail.com'],
             'company': ['a','c','b'],
             'location':['UK','USA','KOREA']})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Attach the `location` column from `key_df` to `data_df` based on two fields - `p_id` and `company`

So, I tried the below

```
loc = key_df.drop_duplicates(['p_id','company']).set_index(['p_id','company'])['location']
data_df['location'] = data_df[['p_id','company']].map(loc)
```

But this resulted in error like below

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['p_id','company'], dtype='object')] are in
> the [columns]"

How can I map based on multiple index columns? I don't wish to use merge

Comment: Why in the second row is abc@gmail.com at company b assigned to location KOREA? That only matches one of the columns in the key_df, not both, so what is the rule?

Comment: will fix the issue. But instead of merge, is it possible to do using `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge can be used for a lot, so let's first try to use it:

```py
data_df.merge(key_df, on=['p_id', 'company'], how="left")
```

```
            p_id company dept_access location
0  abc@gmail.com       a          a1       UK
1  abc@gmail.com       b          a1      NaN
2  abc@gmail.com       c          a1      NaN
3  ace@gmail.com       d          a1      NaN
4  ace@gmail.com       e          a2      NaN
5  pqr@gmail.com       f          a2      NaN
6  pqr@gmail.com       g          a2      NaN
```

You can also do this by mapping the index like this:

```py
idx = ['p_id', 'company']

data_df.assign(location=data_df.set_index(idx).index.map(key_df.set_index(idx)['location']))
```

```
            p_id company dept_access location
0  abc@gmail.com       a          a1       UK
1  abc@gmail.com       b          a1      NaN
2  abc@gmail.com       c          a1      NaN
3  ace@gmail.com       d          a1      NaN
4  ace@gmail.com       e          a2      NaN
5  pqr@gmail.com       f          a2      NaN
6  pqr@gmail.com       g          a2      NaN
```

Comment: is it possible to do using `map`?

Comment: I tried as two seperate lines but still it threw same error - `e = key_df.drop_duplicates(['p_id','company']).set_index(['p_id','company'])['location']
data_df['location'] = data_df.set_index(['p_id','company']).index.map(e)`

Comment: I don't see that error so the data you are using is probably different from what you give in the question. It works here.